# How to check my server Diffie-Hellman MODP size (bits) and increase it?

Tags: linux, openssl, bit, diffie-hellman, redhat-openjdk

Good day,

I have a WAS liberty server in Linux Redhat, and I enable the only TLSv1.2.

I type the following command to get the server info:

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.7.5.65:9443 -msg
```

Part of the result is as follow:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1710 bytes and written 479 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```

I saw the `Server Temp Key` value is DH, 1024 bits, but also saw the Server public key is 2048 bit, may I know my Diffie-Hellman MODP size (bits) is actually 1024 or 2048?

And also the part of the `ServerKeyExchange`

```
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 020f], ServerKeyExchange
    0c 00 02 0b 00 80 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff c9 0f
```

`00 80` convert to decimal is 128, so its means my Diffie-Hellman MODP size (bits) is 1024 bits?

And if its 1024 bits, how can I increase it to 2048 bits?

I am using Java 8 OpenJDK in this server.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it looks like it is 1024 bit for your dhparams. You can generate a new dhparams with openssl:

`openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048`

Then configure your server that is using the dhparams to use the new file, and restart. We did this a long time ago with nginx and apache. There is generally a dhparam file that is used for the system centrally located in /etc for RHEL/CentOS. Replacing that should be sufficient, but if you are using a non-centrally located file, you'll need to modify your configuration accordingly.