# OpenSSL s_client -connect incompatibility issue

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently facing a problem that puzzles me.
When i use this command from a machine with RHEL 7 with OpenSSL 1.0.2k:

```
openssl s_client -connect name.name.somename:9093
```

I get the result i wanted. I can see the cert, the cert chain and etc..

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 CN = XXXXXXX
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*XXXXXXX
   i:/CN=XXXXXXX
 1 s:/CN=XXXXXXX
   i:/CN=XXXXXXX
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
issuer=/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3294 bytes and written 479 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Session-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1638952814
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

But whenever i try the same command from a machine running newer version of OpenSSL i get this error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139685857744704:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 320 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Is there any compatibility issues or some new command or conf file for the newer version?|

Adding all ciphers:

```
Obtaining cipher list from OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021.
Testing TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384...NO (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list)
Testing TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256...NO (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list)
Testing TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256...NO (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384...YES
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256...YES
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256...YES
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA...YES
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AECDH-AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA...YES
Testing DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AECDH-AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-SEED-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES256-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES256-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES256-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES256-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES128-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES128-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES128-CCM8...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES128-CCM...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing CAMELLIA256-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing CAMELLIA256-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AES128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing SEED-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing CAMELLIA128-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing IDEA-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing AECDH-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing NULL-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number)
Testing NULL-MD5...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-NULL-SHA384...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-NULL-SHA256...NO (wrong version number)
Testing PSK-NULL-SHA...NO (wrong version number
```

)

Comment: *...running newer version of OpenSSL...* and what version would that be?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk+ 1.1.x is clear from the sourcefile name so what matters more than the version is how (or by whom) it was built. People doing self-builds rarely bother with FIPS, so [if that's RHEL8, it now has system-wide policies that make OpenSSL on RHEL8 different from OpenSSL elsewhere](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/security_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8). If not, it could be a build tweak of SECLEVEL or the new `ssl_conf` default section (both new in 1.1.x).

Comment: @VeselinUgrinov: please include the output from the successful connection in your question too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i include it in the question too.

Comment: @VeselinUgrinov: Please include the details for the cipher too. But my guess is that there is a weak DH key configured in the server, only 1024 bit based on the output. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626206/what-could-cause-dh-key-too-small-error. Try using `openssl s_client -cipher 'HIGH:!DH' ...` to disable use of DH in the client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i added cipher list from OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021.

Comment: @VeselinUgrinov: I mean the details you've explicitly omitted in `Cipher    : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. And have you tried to disable DH as I proposed?

Comment: I am sorry, i did not get what you mean at first, there is the Cipher value:
  Cipher    : DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , I did not get how to disable DH ... can this be done in the openssl.conf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Testing DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384...YES

It looks like the server supports only DSS ciphers, which is very unusual. As can be seen from [the changelog](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html) such ciphers were removed from the default cipher list with OpenSSL 1.1.0. This means one explicitly need to enable the cipher, i.e.

```
$ openssl s_client -cipher 'DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384' ...
```

Comment: This way it works by adding the -cipher .
I was able to execute openssl s_client -cipher 'DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384' -connect hosntame:9093
But is there any way to add this as a permanent value somewhere, so whenever i execute "openssl s_client -connect hostname:9093" to be able to connect ?

Comment: @VeselinUgrinov: You can override the default setting in the systems openssl config - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level for more

Comment: The part with
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1

did nothing for me ... :/

Comment: @VeselinUgrinov: you need to adapt this string to reflect the ciphers you want, like `CipherString = DEFAULT:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:@SECLEVEL=1`

Comment: Still the same error, but at least " openssl s_client -cipher 'DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384' ..." works, thank you for that.