# Dh key too small OpenSSL: standard fixes do not work

Tags: ssl, openssl, openvpn

I am getting the dh key too small error `OpenSSL: error:1408518A:SSL routines:ssl3_ctx_ctrl:dh key too small`after migrating my OpenVPN server from an older system. However, the standard (low security) fix, commenting out DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2 or changing it to 1 in the openssl.cnf file in /etc/ssl, does not work, and my OpenVPN service still fails to start.

Examples of this proposed fix (not working for me):
[OpenSSL DH Key Too Small Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417224/openssl-dh-key-too-small-error)
[What could cause "dh key too small" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626206/what-could-cause-dh-key-too-small-error)

What could I do?

EDIT: removing the openssl.cnf likewise doesn't fix the issue, so it doesn't appear that that file is being used at all.

Comment: "so it doesn't appear that that file is being used at all." so the first task is most probably to find out which file is used. But that makes your question a sysadmin related one, not a programming related one, so offtopic here.